# Setting a Constant Scroll Speed for a Horizontal Pager in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, jetpack

How can I determine a constant scrolling speed for a horizontal pager using Jetpack Compose? Specifically, I want the scrolling speed to remain constant regardless of how fast the user scrolls.

So far, I've tried using the SnapFlingBehavior class, which provides scrolling behavior at different speeds. However, this solution varies the speed depending on the user's scrolling velocity.

What strategies can I employ to set a constant scrolling speed? For instance, how can I lock the scrolling speed to a specific velocity?

here is my current code ;

```
 HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(10f),
            state = pagerState,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
            flingBehavior = flingBehavior(state = pagerState)



        ) { page ->


            PagerScreen(onBoardingPage = pages[page])

        }
```

I've tried using the `SnapFlingBehavior` class to manage scrolling behavior. While it provides snapping behavior, it doesn't offer a straightforward way to maintain a constant scroll speed. Additionally, I've experimented with adjusting the animation specifications such as `lowVelocityAnimationSpec`, `highVelocityAnimationSpec`, and `snapAnimationSpec` to achieve a constant speed, but with limited success. The behavior still varies based on the user's scrolling velocity.